How to find static assembly instruction address from CE (C++)
I'm trying to edit some value in the memory but it instantly reverts back because of some instruction like player::update or player::reset
In CE I can attach debugger to it and check what's writing into it and replace it with NOP, but how can I get the static address of this instruction?
FYI, I have the static address of my value (playerBase signature scan + known offset) but not instruction address

Just checked, I've got address of this instruction in CE. After restarting my game this address haven't change. I have to restart it again and this changed lol.
However, I decided to WriteProcessMemory() with NOPs array and it didn't worked. Anyone know if Cheat Engine uses VirtualProtect() or something? Because my program literally can't rewrite it...

Below are the steps to find the "Static Instruction Address":
Step 1: Attach Debugger to the Process

Open Cheat Engine (CE).
Attach the debugger to the target process    (the game or application
where your value is located).

Step 2: Find What Writes to the Address

Go to the address of the value you want to edit in Cheat Engine.

Right-click on the address and select "Find out what writes to this
address...".

This will open a new window where the debugger will list    all
instructions that modify this value.


Step 3: Identify the Instruction

Perform an in-game action that causes the value to change (e.g.,
updating or resetting the player).
The instruction that writes to the value will appear in the window.
Note down this instruction.

Step 4: Find the Static Address of the Instruction

Double-click on the instruction to view it in the Disassembler
window.
The instruction might be located in a dynamically loaded module
(e.g., a DLL), which means its address might change every time the
game is restarted.
To find the static address, you need to locate the base address of
the module where this instruction resides.

Step 5: Calculate the Static Address

In the Disassembler window, note down the instruction's address.
Find the base address of the module by clicking "View" > "Memory
Regions..." in Cheat Engine.
Subtract the base address of the module from the instruction’s
address to get the relative offset.
Combine this offset with the module’s base address to form the static
address.

Step 6: Replace Instruction with NOP (Optional)

If your goal is to prevent the instruction from modifying the value,
you can replace it with a NOP (No Operation) instruction directly in
the Disassembler.

Let me show you an example for better understanding:

Let's say the instruction that writes to your value is at
'0x7FF65321F123' and it's located in a module named 'player.dll'.
The base address of 'player.dll' is '0x7FF653200000'.
The offset would be: '0x7FF65321F123' - '0x7FF653200000' = '0x1F123'.
The static address of the instruction would be 'player.dll' + '0x1F123'.


You should signature scan and DON'T use WriteProcessMemory(), it's sucks, just use this:
*(byte*)((DWORD)addressOfAssemblyInstruction) = 0x90;
changing first byte of instruction with NOP
e.g if you wanna change full instruction like mov byte ptr [ebx+0000087B],01
look at the bytes of it
{ 0xC6, 0x83, 0x7B, 0x08, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

then do
void change_address_with_NOP()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        *(byte*)((DWORD)address + i) = 0x90;
    }
}

